# The usage of "on the basis"

Tags: word-usage

I wrote

> In our proposed system, a wrapper is constructed mainly **on the basis of** the anchors identified by the user on a representative page.

What means "on the basis of"? Did I use the phrase correctly? what is your understanding from the sentence above?

In dictionary I found "***on the basis***" as "because of a particular fact or situation", but here I mean anchors are core or fundamental parts on which my data extractor (wrapper) is based.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by it.

Comment: It *looks* okay, but I'm hesitant to endorse your writing, because I don't understand enough about what wrappers and anchors are in this context.

Comment: Fortunately, I am a software developer. A "wrapper" is just a piece of code that allows another, foreign piece of code to interface with your application. "Anchors" are like hidden markers on a web page that can be redirected to -- most common example being a "Back to Top" link at the bottom of a page

Comment: @TRomano Considering my previous posts, you should be familiar with anchor and wrapper in my article, the whole idea of extracting data from web (the wrapper or data extractor) is on the basis of anchors, however in dictionary I found *on the basis* as "because of a particular fact or situation", then it caused me to ask it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the locution "on the basis of X", X usually refers to a fact on which a judgment, decision, assumption, or suspicion is founded.

**On the basis of its smell alone, they believed the chemical to be highly toxic.**

You can simplify:

**....a wrapper *is constructed from* anchors identified by the user on a representative page.**

or "is derived from".

or "is based on".

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to say that you are building a wrapper that exposes the anchors to some other part of your code base, then you got the message across. Otherwise, I am not sure what you could be trying to say.

"On the basis of" is perhaps not the most appropriate phrase to use here. "Basis" means foundation, or fundamental principle. It suggests that you've built the wrapper on *top* of the anchor tags, as if they were the core of your wrapper's function. That sounds weird to me, because anchors don't seem like something you would base some important piece of functionality off of, but I am also not a web developer by trade. I do not know what your implemntation plan is, so you will have to decide if that meaning is accurate or not.

Comment: Thank you that role is what anchors play in my application. My meaning of wrapper is in web mining as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_%28data_mining%29 and my meaning of anchor as some specific texts, constants, patterns within a web document that help me to identify data records